# Wordpress - Theme stuck at loading after migration

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have been recently tasked to migrate a Wordpress page to another hosting services. Task, which should be quite easy, took me last 2 days and I still can't figure out what is wrong. After migrating (tried it with Duplicator plugin, manual copying and changing links in database) pages won't load. I managed to get into backend and after changing theme to any default Wordpress theme (twentysixteen, twentyseveteen etc.) site works fine but when I try use designated theme (Proxima, https://themeforest.net/item/proxima-responsive-business-multipurpose-theme/8094780) it just won't load. Page is trying to load but in the end it shows 503 error. Same thing if I want to see the preview of theme in backend, loading animation appears and nothing happened. I tried a lot of things to fix it: changing file permissions, disabling plugins, updating Wordpress, downgrading Wordpress, changing php version, changing MySQL version and nothing works. My theme support has expired and before I renew it I just wanted to ask if anyone had that problem before. Maybe there is super easy fix and I just don't see it.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: 503 is interesting, I'd expect a 500. Have you looked at the error log? Tried debugging with WP_DEBUG?

Comment: Turned out to be bad media path as the hosting support said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved with hosting support. Bad media path was the problem.